# How can I get intermediate parameters after a training batch in keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I have trained a keras LSTM model. But after training, all i get is the final parameters of the models after training with 10 epochs and batch size=120. How can i get intermediate parameter after a batch keras.
Example: after 120 sample in each batch i can get the intermediate parameter of this step.

I have tried callback method and backend in keras, but i do not know how to get the

'''python

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, 32))
#model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,texts.shape[0])))
model.add(LSTM(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
history_ltsm = model.fit(texts_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=120, validation_split=0.2)
```

'''

I expected the model run step by step based on each batch to show the intermediate parameters, but not the all epochs. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you call intermediate parameters?

Comment: Intermediate parameters is the weights matrix after each batch iterations in training. In the model i get only the final weights matrix by model.get_weights(). But i want to get this each iterations on_batch_end as well. How can ii do this? Thank you!